# Apache Proxy rule not working via AWS ALB for root path

Tags: apache, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a proxy rewrite rule in Apache webserver for the root path ("/").

RewriteRule ^/$ /us/en.html [P,L]

If I access Apache webserer url as http://web-server:80/ , I get 200 response and I see /us/en.html page in browser and url DOES NOT change.

I created AWS ALB and pointed the target group to above webserver. Now if I access root path via ALB url, it does a 301 redirect to /us/en.html

https://alb/ -> 301 redirect -> https://alb/us/en.html

Same thing doesnt happen for any other path , for ex -
if Apache has :

RewriteRule ^/abc /us/en.html [P,L]

then

https://alb/abc -> 200 response, no URL change.

Please advise why only for root path , proxy rule changes to 301 redirect on ALB

Thanks!

RewriteRule ^/$ /us/en.html [P,L]